# Asp.Net Core ActionResult<T> vs ActionResult<Entity<T>>

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

Since the two following controller's actions are possible, I am wondering if there is any difference in terms of performance (or best practices) between them.

```
        [HttpGet("example1")]
        public ActionResult<User> GetExample1()
        {
            var user = new User { UserName = "Example 1 user" };
            var model = new Model<User>(user);
            return Ok(model);
        }

        [HttpGet("example2")]
        public ActionResult<Model<User>> GetExample2()
        {
            var user = new User { UserName = "Example 2 user" };
            var model = new Model<User>(user);
            return Ok(model);
        }
```

Please notice that the only difference between the two is the returned type of the generic parameter of ActionResult (User vs Model<User>). Is there any important internal differences when the ActionResult object is formatting out the result?.

User and Model code for this example:

```
    public class User
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
    }

    public class Model<T>
    {
        public T Data { get; set; }

        public Model(T data)
        {
            Data = data;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What version of .net core are you using?

Comment: <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>